# Paginate Rails object instances looped over in HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

In my Rails app I loop over all the instances of the Product model which fit certain critera and display them on a user's profile page. This is what the loop looks like:

```
<% notsold = @user.products.where("sold_value = false").order("created_at DESC") %>
  <% notsold.each do |f| %>
    <% if f.sold_value === false %>
    // do stuff 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This view is profile.html.erb under the User's controller. What I'm trying to figure out is how to paginate `f`, or each of the products in the created array. I have the will_paginate gem installed. Here is the profile action in users_controller.rb:

```
def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: if something is not clear, please ask me, do not give negative score. otherwise no one will answer your question again

Answer (score 0):

you can provide `@products` instance variable in controller like this

```
@products = @user.products.where("sold_value = false").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

Then you can loop `@products` in your code

```
<% @products.each do |f| %>
  <% if f.sold_value === false %>
    // do stuff 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question of how to paginate it.

Comment: did you see my code ".paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)"